# How to get second asset in Craft CMS 4?

Tags: assets, craft4

In craft cms 3 we could use this:

```
{{ entry.images[1].url }}
```

But how can I get second asset in Craft CMS 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the element query, then access the second element of the resulting array:

```twig
{% set secondImage = entry.images.all()[1].url ?? null %}
{% if secondImage %}
    {# … #}
{% endif %}
```

The null coalescing operator (`??`) is useful here to prevent errors in case there aren't two images selected in the `images` field.

Comment: Just need to replace `images().` by `images.`

Comment: I can't edit it as stackexchange demand at least 6 changed characters :)

Comment: @NikolayBronskiy Ah yes, good catch, slip of the pen :)